GCP loadbalancer doesn't work with IAP(Identity-Aware Proxy) settings
I have my loadbalancer in GCP which has HTTPS frontend with my certificate and SSL policy set on my domain. After enabled IAP(Identity-Aware Proxy) in backend, the OAuth consent screen works well when accessing the frontend URL, but following error displays after I log in using Google account in OAuth consent screen.

There was a problem with your request. Please reference
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq#error_codes. Error code 53

After checking Google's guide in error message, I got following offical solution from https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/allowed-domains

If you receive Error code 53, ask an IAP administrator to add your
host name to the list of allowed domains.

But I have already set both my PC's host name and domain name which used for SSL policy to the list of allowed domains in IAP. I'm not sure what's the root cause of this, based on Google's official information. Anyone can help me on this? Thank you!

Do you have any wildcard entries in your domain like (*.mydomain.com)?

Indeed, you must add your allowed domain in the OAuth config page. And, sometime, wait for a while for propagation (15 minutes)

@DharaniDharGolladasari Yes I added *both mydomain.com and .mydomain.com

@guillaumeblaquiere Thank you, but do you mean the setting of OAuth consent screen? How to add domain there? I have tried adding Google account to Test User there, also I tried publishing OAuth to production, didn't work.

Yes, API & Services -> OAuth  consent screen. Click on "edit app" (top of the page,on the right of the first like Cloud Endpoint API Keys) and add your domain in authorized domains.

Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere, it seems not the cause of my end. I tried this, now I can assess my app via domain URL(routing to frontend IP) with Google account authentication.
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run#enabling Follow the instructions at Access control with IAM to authorize IAP to send traffic to the backend Cloud Run service. Principal: service-[PROJECT-NUMBER]@gcp-sa-iap.iam.gserviceaccount.com, Role: Cloud Run Invoker. But the error didn't change when accessing frontend IP directly.

You mean you still have your error 53? maybe you should fix this Cloud Run authorization issue first. The error is pretty explicit, you should be able to fix it easily.
